# Is it possible to use SPI within an age_ function?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I was wondering if I could utilize [SPI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html) to access the server and perform a query to return an `agtype` value. I wanted to implement a function that uses an already created one but then perform an `ORDER BY` and then return the `agtype` results from there. Would that be possible? If this is not possible, how could call another `age_` function inside another and retrieve it's results and use `ODER BY` with it?

Comment: I have removed the "spi" tag as it is used for the *Serial Peripheral Interface* and not for *Server Programming Interface*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the SPI (Server Programming Interface), but you could look in fmgr.h for the `DirectFunctionCall` family of functions, which provide various ways to call other functions inside C.

Here's an example that demonstrates the usage:

```
Datum result;
result = DirectFunctionCall2(numeric_add, num1, num2);
```

In this code snippet, the `DirectFunctionCall2` function is used to call another function that adds two numeric values and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

The SPI mechanism should work fine, but I think `transform_cypher_order_by` function is responsible for handling the `ORDER BY` clause. You should experiment with it and see if it works.

Comment: In which file and folder is this function located?

Comment: src/backend/parser/cypher_clause.c

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use the server programming interface in PostgreSQL to work on and perform queries and access the server. Moreover, the ORDER BY query can also be used within the AGE function for custom domains.